# How to dynamically mask a text field with swift

Tags: ios, swift, input-mask

I'm trying to use a dynamic mask for a text field according to the number of characters entered.

I tried to use VMaskTextField, AKMaskField and now I'm using InputMask (https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-ios) and I was only able to make one of the masks work. I want to mask as ###.###.###-## or ##.###.###/####-## but I couldn't make to change the mask while the user types. I followed two wiki posts https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-ios/wiki/Quick-Start and https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-ios/wiki/2.1-Affine-Masks.

Here my actual code:

```
 @IBOutlet var btnEntrar: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var txtCpfCnpj: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var listener: MaskedTextFieldDelegate!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        listener.affinityCalculationStrategy = .prefix
        listener.primaryMaskFormat = "[000].[000].[000]-[00]"
        listener.affineFormats = [
            "[00].[000].[000]/[0000]-[00]"
        ]

    }
```

Here is the main.storyboard:

[image: Main.storyboard]

I created the listener as suggested on the wiki posts and it's now working. The field doesn't accept more characters than 11 characters, which corresponds to the first mask ([000].[000].[000]-[00])

Does anyone know how to this dynamic mask in any other way or using some framework?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`InputMask` author here.

`MaskedTextFieldDelegate` switches between available masks based on its [`AffinityCalculationStrategy`](https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-ios/blob/master/Source/InputMask/InputMask/Classes/Helper/AffinityCalculationStrategy.swift). According to your code, you are using a `.prefix` strategy, which won't do the trick unless the end user types that dot symbol all by himself.

Unfortunately, the second strategy currently available to you (the `.wholeString` one) won't help you out neither.

It seems obvious to me that the library currently lacks one more `AffinityCalculationStrategy` based on the input value length. I'm going to add it over this weekend, so please stay tuned.

UPD. I've made a [feature request](https://github.com/RedMadRobot/input-mask-ios/issues/72) regarding this functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just saw your feature request. I ended up doing two masks but I will get your new version and test it. Thanks again!

Comment: @Jeorge Taflanidi: I have an existing project targetting iOS 12. I added  pod 'InputMask' in my pod file and did an install. I now see the project in my Pods section. I select the UITextField that I want to mask but I can't see MaskedTextFieldDelegate in the custum class drop down. Any hint ?